# Docker-machine : How to exec an ssh command correctly?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am running Docker on my OS X local host. I created a dev' machine, and I am trying to run a command upon SSH to my dev machine :

```
~$ docker-machine ssh dev -- ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' \
   -i /Users/yves/.docker/machine/machines/dev/id_rsa \
   -N -L 5000:localhost:5000 root@harbor.dufour16.net &
```

I get:

```
[1] 28171
~$ exit status 255
```

Then I don't get any prompt back. I need to use CTRL-C , and I get:

```
[1]+  Exit 1 docker-machine ssh dev -- ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking 
 no' -i /Users/yves/.docker/machine/machines/dev/id_rsa 
-N -L 5000:localhost:5000 root@harbor.dufour16.net
```

Is there a way to execute it correctly ? (Using boot2docker it was easier as the command to be executed was quoted). Thanks for feedback.

Comment: `docker-machine ssh` takes exactly two args; don't you just need to put everything after dev in quotes?

Comment: it seems quotes is not accepted .. need to use the -- separator ...
 see https://docs.docker.com/machine/     sub-command ssh  (unless I read wrong..)

If the command you are appending has flags, e.g. df -h, you can use the flag parsing terminator (--) to avoid confusing the docker-machine client, which will otherwise interpret them as flags you intended to pass to it:

Comment: OK. I had a similar issue and wrapping in quotes was the only way I got it to work.

Comment: you mean    docker-machine ssh dev "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' \
> >    -i /Users/yves/.docker/machine/machines/dev/id_rsa \
> >    -N -L 5000:localhost:5000 root@harbor.dufour16.net &" &   I guess    so write it as an answer ... I'll vote for it thanks

Comment: Ok. BTW does using `&` work? I would have thought you'd need to use nohup.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use quotes i.e:

```
ssh dev "ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' \
        -i /Users/yves/.docker/machine/machines/dev/id_rsa \
        -N -L 5000:localhost:5000 root@harbor.dufour16.net &"
```